# How does useQuery not require a memoized callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

`useQuery` from `react-query` package doesn't require you to `useCallback` to memoize the callback you pass to `useQuery`.

I'm trying to create a simple kind of similar hook but struggling with how to get around this issue, I don't want to require the extra step of always memoizing the provided callback.

Comment: Try looking at the [source code](https://github.com/TanStack/query)

Comment: I've tried, it's so much more than a simple query helper hook like what I'm trying to make that I can't tell what part is accomplishing solving just this issue specifically vs part of other robust stuff it has.

I'm trying to figure out what is the simplest way to solve that issue without having to make a higher order arg parser and a base query fn that calls a base base query fn, lol.

Comment: Why would they require to memoize that callback?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski if the caller of the hook doesn’t memoize the given cb then every time The component re-renders due to a state change it will trigger the hook’s useEffect to rerun due to the cb being a dependency and this can cause an infinite rerender loop in the component so I think they do something else to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that they just cache requests based only on props passed to the QueryKey
and the reference for the Query Function doesn't matter at all?

Comment: Obviously that is meant as a rhetoric question, I can tell that. But I do not get how it is supposed to answer the question at the top of his page or provide a solution to the described problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33145530)